# Check if a number is in range and output to a file

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that automatically sorts something for me

I have a list of different bots with points. It looks somewhat like this:

> BOT#1 | POINTS BALANCE = 39 | POINTS EARNED = 2000

I want python to open my file(list) and iterate through the list and output the bots based on their value
so I'd look something like this

```
BOT#1 | POINTS BALANCE = 100 | POINTS EARNED = 2000
BOT#2 | POINTS BALANCE = 200 | POINTS EARNED = 2023
BOT#3 | POINTS BALANCE = 300 | POINTS EARNED = 9300
BOT#4 | POINTS BALANCE = 400 | POINTS EARNED = 1030
```

For every 100 points python makes   a new file and puts all bots with the points in there (the entire line)

so

> BOT#1 | POINTS BALANCE = 100 | POINTS EARNED = 2000

would go into a file called "100" and python would write the entire line to the new file.

I'm sorry if this is confusing, I really don't know where to start on this and I am terrible at explaining.

tldr:
I want python to open my file, go through the list and scrape the value for

> POINTS BALANCE = value

and then per 100 it makes a new file and writes the entire line it took from the original file to it.

Comment: As always, post some code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
t = ['BOT#1 | POINTS BALANCE = 100 | POINTS EARNED = 2000', 'BOT#2 | POINTS BALANCE = 200 | POINTS EARNED = 2023', 'BOT#3 | POINTS BALANCE = 300 | POINTS EARNED = 9300', 'BOT#4 | POINTS BALANCE = 400 | POINTS EARNED = 1030']
t = [line.replace("BOT#", "").replace("POINTS BALANCE =", "").replace("POINTS EARNED =","").split("|") for line in t]
t = np.array(t).astype(int)
points_balance = np.unique(t[:,1])
by_point = {}
for p in points_balance:
    rows = t[t[:,1]==p]
    rows = ["BOT#{} | POINTS BALANCE = {} | POINTS EARNED = {}".format(*row) for row in rows]
    by_point[p] = rows
```

The output will be a dictionary of the rows by the balance points, and you can write each of them to a file

```
{100: ['BOT#1 | POINTS BALANCE = 100 | POINTS EARNED = 2000'], 200: ['BOT#2 | POINTS BALANCE = 200 | POINTS EARNED = 2023'], 300: ['BOT#3 | POINTS BALANCE = 300 | POINTS EARNED = 9300'], 400: ['BOT#4 | POINTS BALANCE = 400 | POINTS EARNED = 1030']}
```